# Why `system("cls")` works only if it is called by a certain function?

Tags: c, function

I am developing a simple hotel reservation management system, but I've encountered a little problem. The `system("cls");` in `mainMenu()` function doesn't work, only if the `mainMenu()` function is called by the `bookRoom()` function. I tried works just fine with other function, I have no idea why this happens.

Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

char exitOpt[1],cfm[1];;
int mainMenu_Opt;
int chk = 0;
int advance[4] = {750, 500, 250, 125};
int roomFee[4] = {1500, 1000, 500 ,250};
int rT[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int roomAvail[4] = {1,2,2,5};

struct guest{
    char id[5];
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int r_type;
    int chk_in_date;
    int chk_out_date;
    int per;
    int totPay;
    int paid;
    int balance;
};
struct guest grec;

FILE *fguest,*ftemp;

void main();
void mainMenu();
void checkRoom();
void putRAV();
int bookRoom();
void vldRT();
void readData();
void exitProgram ();

void mainMenu()
{   
    system("cls");

    for(;;)
    {   
        fguest = fopen("guest_list.dat","rb");
        while(fread(&grec,sizeof(grec),1,fguest)==1 )
        {
            if (grec.r_type == chk)
                roomAvail[chk-1]--;
        }
        chk = 0;
        fclose(fguest);     
        printf("\n     Welcome to HRMS \n\n");
        printf("\tMain Menu\n\n");
        printf("1. Check Room's Availability\n\n");
        printf("2. Book A Room\n\n");
        printf("3. Check Out a Room Guest\n\n");
        printf("4. Edit Reservation\n\n");
        printf("5. Search\n\n");
        printf("6. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please, enter your choice (1-6): ");
        scanf("%d",&mainMenu_Opt);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(mainMenu_Opt)
        {
            case 1: {   putRAV();
                        break;          }

            case 2: {
                        bookRoom();
                        break;          }

//          case 3: {   chkoRoom();                 
//                      break;          }
//          
//          case 4: {   editRes();                  
//                      break;          }
//          
            case 5: {   readData();                 
                        break;          }

            case 6: {   exitProgram(); 
                        break;          }

            default: printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again with valid input (whole number between 1 - 6).\n ");
        }
    }
}

void checkRoom()
{   
    system("cls");
    fguest = fopen("guest_list.dat","rb");
    while(fread(&grec,sizeof(grec),1,fguest)==1 )
    {
        switch (grec.r_type)
        {
            case 1: {
                        roomAvail[0]--; 
                        break;                  }
            case 2: {
                        roomAvail[1]--;
                        break;                  }
            case 3: {
                        roomAvail[2]--; 
                        break;                  }   
            case 4: {
                        roomAvail[3]--; 
                        break;                  }
        }   
    }
    fclose(fguest);
}

void putRAV()
{   
    system("cls");
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {   
        printf("%d\n", roomAvail[j]);
    }

    printf("Back to main (Y/N)?: "); gets(cfm); fflush(stdin);
    if ((strcmp(cfm,"Y")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"y")==0))
    {   printf("Returning to main menu...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        mainMenu();                                     }
    else if ((strcmp(cfm,"N")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"n")==0))
    {   putRAV();                                           }           
    else
    {   printf("\nInvalid Input. Returning to ReadData\n");
        putRAV();                                       }
}

int bookRoom()
{   
    system("cls");
    fflush(stdin);
    grec.totPay = 0;
    fguest = fopen("guest_list.dat","ab+");
    printf("\n\tBook A Room");
    printf("\n\nGuest\'s ID\t\t: ");    scanf("%s",grec.id);                fflush(stdin);
    printf("Guest\'s Name\t\t: ");      scanf("%30s",grec.name);            fflush(stdin);
    printf("Guest\'s Age\t\t: ");       scanf("%d",&grec.age);              fflush(stdin);
    printf("Room\'s Type\t\t: ");       scanf("%d",&grec.r_type);           fflush(stdin);
    vldRT();
    printf("Check-in Date\t\t: ");      scanf("%d",&grec.chk_in_date);      fflush(stdin);
    printf("Check-out Date\t\t: ");     scanf("%d",&grec.chk_out_date);     fflush(stdin);
    printf("Staying Period\t\t: ");     scanf("%d",&grec.per);              fflush(stdin);
    grec.totPay = (roomFee[grec.r_type - 1] * grec.per) - advance[grec.r_type-1];
    printf("Total Payment\t\t: %d\n", grec.totPay); 
    printf("Total Paid\t\t: ");         scanf("%d",&grec.paid);             fflush(stdin);
    grec.balance = grec.totPay - grec.paid;
    printf("Balance\t\t\t: %d \n\n",grec.balance);
    printf("\t\t Confirm Booking (Y/N)?: "); gets(cfm);                     fflush(stdin);
    if ((strcmp(cfm,"Y")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"y")==0))
    {   fwrite(&grec,sizeof(grec),1,fguest);
        fclose(fguest); 
        chk = grec.r_type;
        printf("Room successfully booked...\n");
        printf("Returning to main menu...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        return chk;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(cfm,"N")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"n")==0))
    {   bookRoom();                                             }           
    else
    {   printf("\nInvalid Input. Returning to Book A Room\n");
        bookRoom();                                             }   
    mainMenu();
}

void vldRT()
{
    if (grec.r_type <= 0 || grec.r_type >4)
    {
        printf("Invalid input!! Input must be between 1 - 4\n");
        printf("Please try again:\n");                          
        printf("Room\'s Type\t\t: ");       scanf("%d",&grec.r_type);           fflush(stdin);  }

}

void exitProgram ()
{
    printf("\nExit program (Y/N)? "); gets(exitOpt); fflush(stdin);
    if ((strcmp(exitOpt,"Y")==0) || (strcmp(exitOpt,"y")==0))
        exit(0);
    else if ((strcmp(exitOpt,"N")==0) || (strcmp(exitOpt,"n")==0))
        mainMenu();
    else 
        printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again with valid input (Y/N). \n");
        exitProgram();
}

void readData()
{   
    system("cls");
    fguest = fopen("guest_list.dat","rb");
    rewind(fguest);
    while(fread(&grec,sizeof(grec),1,fguest)==1)        //continue reading until there's no more struct data
    {
        printf("\n\nGuest\'s ID\t\t: %s", grec.id);
        printf("\nGuest\'s Name\t\t: %s",grec.name);        
        printf("\nGuest\'s Age\t\t: %d",grec.age);      
        printf("\nRoom\'s Type\t\t: %d",grec.r_type);       
        printf("\nCheck-in Date\t\t: %d",grec.chk_in_date); 
        printf("\nCheck-out Date\t\t: %d",grec.chk_out_date);   
        printf("\nStaying Period\t\t: %d",grec.per);            
        printf("\nTotal Payment\t\t: %d", grec.totPay); 
        printf("\nTotal Paid\t\t: %d",grec.paid);
        printf("\nBalance\t\t\t: %d \n\n",grec.balance);
    }
    fclose(fguest);
    printf("Back to main (Y/N)?: "); gets(cfm); fflush(stdin);
    if ((strcmp(cfm,"Y")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"y")==0))
    {   printf("Returning to main menu...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        mainMenu();                                     }
    else if ((strcmp(cfm,"N")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"n")==0))
    {   readData();                                         }           
    else
    {   printf("\nInvalid Input. Returning to ReadData\n");
        readData();                                         }   

}

void main()
{   
    checkRoom();
    mainMenu();
}
```

Comment: Using `system("cls");` is not going to work win non-windows systems either. After `fopen()` ALWAYS check against `NULL`

Comment: `system("cls")` is an inefficient, non-portable hack.

Comment: @iharob  portability is not why im tryin for so far.. coz i develop it for a college assg which is just testing coding ability  in C

Comment: Well `system("cls");` is not going going to test any ability at all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart its for a uni assignment, portability is not one of the marking criteria. thats why im nt tryin for tht

Comment: @iharob ok.. so i should try alternative to system("cls")?

Comment: @iharob i will add the check for NULL once i gt everything working

Comment: Never `fflush(stdin);`, that's undefined behavior. And figure out what terminal you're using and how to clear it using just a `puts()`, it will be lots smaller, faster and more testable.

Comment: Your program is full of all kinds of completely crazy recursive calls, which will ultimately cause all kinds of random bugs. Your code has an invalid form of main and will not compile on standard C compilers. It should not have a prototype. The code `fflush(stdin);` is a bug that invokes undefined behavior. You should never write an empty parenthesis behind a function in C, you should write `(void)`. And so on. Overall, you need a new source of C learning.

Comment: @Lundin aww.. but isnt it is okay if i have condition to stop the recursive calls? 
so i should chg my main function back to int main() and remove the function prototype and put void for every function parameter?

Comment: You just need to rewrite the code so that it uses more conventional program design. As in, call the functions from a switch like you do, return an exit code, check the exit code from the caller, and if execution should continue, loop.

Comment: prototypes for functions that have no parameters should have `void` between the parens, otherwise the compiler produces code as if those functions could have any number of parameters.   Do not prototype the `main()` function

Comment: when calling OS functions like: `system()` and `fopen()`, etc.  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there is no need to put braces '{' and '}' around the body of a `case` statement.

Comment: regarding these statements: `gets(cfm); fflush(stdin);`  1) NEVER use `gets()` as it has no protection from input buffer overruns AND is not even in the latest C standard.  2) the function: `fflush()` is only defined for output streams, not input streams,

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value(s)) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: when a file has just been opened, there is no need to call `rewind()` as opening the file will place the 'file position pointer' at the beginning of the file.

Comment: this line: `if ((strcmp(cfm,"Y")==0) || (strcmp(cfm,"y")==0))` will probably not work correctly as each line read in will contain a trailing '\n' (newline) sequence.

Comment: it is unlikely that the check in and check out dates are a single integer.  More likely they are a string similar to `mm/dd/yyyy` I.E. 02/22/2016 which is not an integer.   The `pay` and `totpay` fields need to allow for 'cents',

Comment: in function: `exitProgram()`,  the call to `mainMenu()` is recursive.  And the menu already has the users' selection to exit the program, so no need to be inputting more data from the user.

Comment: this line: `printf("Staying Period\t\t: ");     scanf("%d",&grec.per);` gets useless data, much better to get how many persons will be staying in the room.

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with the `%s` format specifier, always include a max characters modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid any buffer overflow problems, Such overflow results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: for clarity, function names should indicate what the function will do, usually via an active verb being part of the name.  this function name: `vldRT` means nothing, even in the current context.

Comment: the array `cfm` is only one character long. however, calls to `scanf()` are using a `%s` format specifier, which will always append a NUL byte to the input, so that array will always be overrun,  That is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: in the function: `mainMenu()` the screen is only cleared one, at the beginning of the function. suggest clearing the screen as the first thing at the top of each loop when the displaying of the menu

Comment: Although high level English is not expected here, following a [minimal set of the spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is gladly welcomed.

Comment: @peterh,  If your addressing my comments.  I wrote them when very tired and did not notice the problem(s) until much later,  By which time 5 minutes has elapsed and the comment cannot be modified (except by deleting and re-writing)

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry, no harm - I wrote it to the OP (meanwhile I fixed also the question, as I could).

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that `system("cls")` "*doesn't work*"?

Answer (score -2):

Why not make your own cls function that is portable?

```
void my_cls(void) {
  int i = 5000;
  while (i-->0)
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: but the next content to show will show up from bottom left corner?

Comment: there are several problems with this approach.  Also, much better to use the appropriate escape sequence, such as `033[1:1H` to move the cursor to upper left corner, followed by `033[j` to erase the display

Comment: @user3629249 OP uses Windows. Only recent Windows 10 installs have a terminal that supports such ANSI sequences.

Comment: This won't work if the terminal is taller than 50 lines. You can't hope to make this kind of thing work on both POSIX and Windows.

Comment: @Rhymoid,  I've been using the CSI escape sequences on windows, all the way back to the days of DOS.  They always worked as expected.

Comment: Still don't see why this was thumbed down so many times, other than the reason that the cursor would be at the bottom instead of top right corner.